# HDMI passing sound but no picture from MacBook Pro

Tags: hdmi

My HDMI is not working as usual. I can hear the correct sound, but no picture. I believe the last software update may have been the cause. I have attached a friend's MacBook Pro and the HDMI works correctly.

I am running a 2015 MacBook Pro with macOS 10.12.4.